# How can I update variables on jsp page without reloading page?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, jsp

I have a jsp page where i have several varibles, all of the variables will have different values in every seconds because some codes in the backend will change them. When the user load the following page will see these numbers az zero but as the time passes these values should be updated and displayed at this page, so basically it should look like a time counter.

Here is my jsp page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Process</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:aquamarine;">
<h2>${info}</h2>
<h2>Number of Xs:</h2>
<h2>${numberOfX}</h2>
<h2>Completed Xs:</h2>
<h2>${completedInfo}</h2>
<h2>Elapsed time:</h2>
<h2>${elapsedTime}</h2>
<form action="/" method="get">
    <table>
    <tr>    
    <td><input type="submit" name="button1" value="BACK" /></td>                                            
    </tr>
    </table>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately jsps are populated once with the model data.

You can use server side events though: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-sse-streams